# Trying to use referances to an object for another class

Tags: c++, oop, reference

My problem is, I can't seem to send an object by referance to another class.  I have had little luck looking this up on the 'net.  If you could please examine my source and let me know if you have any ideas. TYIA -Roland

I also get these errors

```
 error: field 'PgmClass' has incomplete type
 error: 'PgmClass' does not name a type
 error: expected ')' before 'thesource'
 error: 'm_hereitis' was not declared in this scope
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pgmclass.h"
#include "inclobj.h"

int main()
{

    char catchcin[256];

    PgmClass wilko;

    wilko.addToSet( 7 );
    wilko.addToSet( 8 );
    wilko.addToSet( 9 );

    InclObj alpha( wilko );

    wilko.addToSet( 10 );
    wilko.addToSet( 11 );

    // This doesn't work
    alpha.eraseOne( 10 );

    // How can I get this to work using referances?

    std::cout << "Program Running." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> catchcin;

    return 0;
}


----------

#include <set>

class PgmClass  {

      public:
    int addToSet( int );
    bool eraseSet( int );
    std::set<int> m_userset;
};

int PgmClass::addToSet( int theint )    {

    m_userset.insert( theint );
}

bool PgmClass::eraseSet( int eraseint )  {

    m_userset.erase( eraseint );
}


----------

class InclObj   {

      public:
    InclObj( PgmClass );
    void eraseOne( int );

    PgmClass m_hereitis;
};

InclObj::InclObj( PgmClass thesource )    {

    m_hereitis = thesource;
}

void InclObj::eraseOne( int findint )    {

    m_hereitis.eraseSet( findint );
}
```

Comment: Normally, you include header files, not cpp files.

Comment: you should not include a cpp file

Comment: You should include headers.

Comment: Do not #include .cpp files. We already told you in your `c1` global object question.

Comment: Thou shalt not includeth thy cpp phile.

Comment: @RolandSams okay, then try to assume the error your compiler is spilling out isn't actually an error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the files.  I will keep it in mind

Comment: The comments about the files are as good as answers - that **IS** the problem.

Comment: I don't see any references here.

Comment: @RolandSams We can't just assume that. The problem is probably that the definition of some member function of one of the classes needs to see the definition of the other class, but can't. You can solve this by putting class definitions in .h files, putting function definitions (=bodies) in .cpp files, and including the .h files in the .cpp files.

Comment: Ok, can you give me a link to a site that has resources for .h and .cpp file contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your main at the end of the file. (Normaly you add the class in a separate .h file -with the implementation in another .cpp file-, with you include before use the class). 
Define, the member as reference:

```
class InclObj
{

      public:
            InclObj( PgmClass& );
            void eraseOne( int );

            PgmClass& m_hereitis;
};

InclObj::InclObj( PgmClass& thesource ) :  m_hereitis (thesource)
{

}
```

Doing this you assume some responsibilities. For example, don’t use `eraseOne()` after the original object has been deleted. Don’t try to add a function like `InclObj::use_now_this_other_object(PgmClass& other_source)`, etc.  But I assumed you know about…

Comment: Ahh, this looks promising.  I will confirm it works tomorrow (I have been programming for over 12 hours.  Thank you very much sir.